# required field within a jquery accordion

Tags: jquery, validation, jquery-ui-accordion

Basic form using a JQuery Accordion and attempting to validate required fields. Am I missing something simple?  Thanks!

**javascript:**

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#accordion").accordion();
        $("#Form1").validate({
            rules: {
                AccordionField: { required: true }
            }
        });
    });    
</script>
```

**html:**

```
<form id="Form1" action="foo.htm">
    <div id="accordion">
    <h3><a href="#">Section 1</a></h3>
    <div><p>content</p></div>
    <h3><a href="#">Section 2</a></h3>
    <div><p><input id="AccordionField" class="required" /></p></div>
    </div>
    <p><button type="submit">Submit</button></p>
</form>
```

**Problem:**
If the second section is collapsed during the submit, validation does not validate the required field.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

jQuery validate (1.9) ignores hidden fields by default. You can override this behavior using the `ignore` option:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#accordion").accordion();
    $("#Form1").validate({
        rules: {
            AccordionField: {
                required: true
            }
        },
        ignore: []
    });
});​
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/andrewwhitaker/VWWkP/