# Required MVC Field in a Jquery Accordion

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui, asp.net-mvc-4

Hey so I have a very similar question as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9738112/required-field-within-a-jquery-accordion) one here on SF. I have a required field inside of a jquery UI Accordion. If that field is visible (i.e. its accordion is open) the validation works just fine. If I switch the accordion to a different view though, it doesn't work.

Now I know MVC using the same jquery validation that is referenced in that question above, and by putting the ignore tags it works, but how would I do that in with ASP.NET MVC validation?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out after multiple attempts the syntax is similar to the question above:

```
$('#Form').validate().settings.ignore = []
```

Interestingly when doing it like the above question it didn't work, but this does. Who knows!